How did Jesus' disciples know that he could dispense them from the Pharisees' traditions?
Jesus and his disciples follow Jesus' interpretation of the Mosaic law rather than that of the Pharisees on several occasions (i.e. Mt 12, 15).  But isn’t it true that they had no way of proving Jesus' divinity at that point?  Doesn’t that mean that from their perspective they were being disobedient to the Pharisees?

"Jesus clearly encourages his disciples to break the Mosaic Law on several occasions (i.e. Mt 12, 15)." — It isn't clear at all. In fact, it simply isn't true.  Notice that the Pharisees ask "Why do thy disciples transgress the tradition of the elders?"; it was their tradition, not the Law that was being broken. ¶ This question really has no basis as currently worded. Changing "Mosaic Law" to "Pharisaic rules" would improve it a lot.

@wmasse - Your edit of 10/8/24 removes several points that I responded to and leaves me tilting in the wind, so to speak. Polishing a question is fine but changing it so dramatically once it has already been addressed is not advisable.

@DanFefferman This question was originally written by a demon that I was collaborating with, so I am just trying to mitigate the damage.

@wmasse as much as I hate to propagate the works of the demonic. The point of posting on this site is that you "give it away" once you post. If you want to ask this question, you should ask it.  I think you need to revert your chances.  Since I'm an answerer, I've got a conflict of interest as a mod, our normal procedure is to revert your changes (your conscience should be clean though) the only alternative is to vote to delete the question.

@PeterTurner As far as I can tell the answers still make sense because what I got rid of was just false information.

The question is rather complex, so I will address several points briefly.

In Matthew 12 and 15, Jesus engages the Pharisees in a halakhic debate: an argument on the proper interpretation of the Law. In Mt. 15 (the issue of hand-washing) he is on solid ground because there is no Torah law requiring hand-washing before meals. This is specifically described as a "tradition of the elders" not a Law of Moses. In Mt. 12, his position did seem to go against the letter of the Law, but he argued that since the "Sabbath is made for man" (and not the other way around) gleaning the fields was allowed on the Sabbath. This policy certainly must have raised eyebrows but there were all kinds of arguments among the rabbis about what was and was not allowed on the Sabbath. Jesus was on the "liberal" side of this debate, others - such as the Essenes - were so strict as to forbid even moving one's bowels on the Sabbath.

Regarding "heresy," neither of the above examples rises to that level. Rabbis often disagreed about how the law should be interpreted and applied in daily life.

Jesus did recognize Pharisaic legal authority in Mt 21:2-3. But he, like the Pharisees, was a rabbi and had the right to interpret the Law. Here in Matthew, he instructs his disciples to follow the local rabbi's teaching when he is not present. He did not instruct his disciples to blaspheme.

"The Son of Man is Lord of the Sabbath" does not necessarily mean that Jesus was overriding the Law. It can also be understood to mean that he was a Master of the Sabbath in the same sense that other Jews were known as the masters of reading, prayer, or repentance. Having carefully observed the Sabbath throughout his life Jesus was qualified to instruct his disciples in its proper observance.

"He declared all food clean," is a quote from Mark 7:19, not Mt. 15. It is an editorial comment by the author, not a statement of Jesus. Such a statement would be uncharacteristic of Matthew's attitude toward the Law.

"He did things as if he were God."  The prophets too did this, sometimes in shocking fashion. (e.g. Moses was "as God" to Aaron. Hosea took a "wife of prostitution" because he represented God's enduring commitment to Israel, who had "played the harlot" with other gods.) It was not blasphemous for a rabbi to teach with God's authority.


Conclusion: Jesus interpreted the Law of Moses differently from other rabbis in a few cases. But in the Gospel of Matthew, he is depicted as generally upholding the Law and the authority of the rabbis (of which he was one) to interpret it. His disciples did take a risks by following him, because they believed him to be the Messiah; and to follow him put them in a precarious position with Rome, the Temple authorities and some of the Pharisees.

If Jesus was who he claimed to be, then it was a matter of salvation for his followers to trust him, but not just because of what he said - because of what he did to prove that he was who he claimed to be.
Jesus set the example of keeping the law of Moses by healing people on the sabbath day and stopping them going astray. After all, that law stated that if a person saw their neighbour's domestic animal gone astray, or so burdened that it could not get up, they must return it to the owner, or raise up that poor, helpless animal. Exodus 23:4-5. Was there an exception to helping their neighbour's animal on the sabbath-day? Legalistic pedants might say so. Hard-hearted people would have no care for the plight of people suffering even more than domestic animals on sabbath days. That was what Jesus was dealing with, and he deliberately healed many people on the sabbath day. Just read John 9:1 to 41. I challenge you to read the entire chapter carefully, seeking to understand how Jesus combined his claims with miracles that nobody without the power of God could possibly do.
Bear in mind that before that particular miracle of giving sight to a man born blind from birth, disciples such as Simon Peter had acclaimed Jesus to be the Messiah, the Son of God (Matthew 16:13-27). And he had confirmed that it was God the Father in heaven who had disclosed that fact.
The question would better be, "How could Jesus' disciples NOT trust him given all that they witnessed him do, and heard his profound teaching, including that he came to fulfill the law?" (Matthew 5:17) His teaching and his many miracles proved him to be who he claimed to be, but those who trust in religious systems and laws to demonstrate their own supposed righteousness will get their reward in this life - the approval of men of like-mind. Yes, it was a good thing that Jesus' disciples trusted him, he in whom there was no sin. Anyone accusing Jesus of sin needs to think very carefully about what they are really saying.

It might be easy to see things like this right now, but there are two things in the Bible worth considernig
One, consider Gamaliel, in the Book of Acts:

But a Pharisee named Gamaliel, a teacher of the law, who was honored by all the people, stood up in the Sanhedrin and ordered that the men be put outside for a little while. 35 Then he addressed the Sanhedrin: “Men of Israel, consider carefully what you intend to do to these men. 36 Some time ago Theudas appeared, claiming to be somebody, and about four hundred men rallied to him. He was killed, all his followers were dispersed, and it all came to nothing. After him, Judas the Galilean appeared in the days of the census and led a band of people in revolt. He too was killed, and all his followers were scattered. Therefore, in the present case I advise you: Leave these men alone! Let them go! For if their purpose or activity is of human origin, it will fail. But if it is from God, you will not be able to stop these men; you will only find yourselves fighting against God.”
Acts 5:34-39 - NIV

Gamaliel certainly would be admitting that the followers of Jesus were OK in their blasphemy (Which I think you mean by heresy).  There would be absolutely no justification for Gamaliel to say this if the followers of Jesus were seen as heretics.  They must not have been seen as abject blasphemers because no respected teacher of the law could say this about them.
Two, Jesus says specifically that He didn't come to upend the old law, but to complete it (Mt 5:17).  He specifically expands and moralizes the law (think why you shouldn't look at a woman with lust or call your brother a fool etc...).
In the words of G.K. Chesterton, he "broke the conventions, but kept the commandments" - and in doing that Jesus showed, even more than He preached, that the kingdom of God was within you and what came out of you was what defiled you.  It was completely consistent to go against things that were simply conventional because those do not have the power to save.

They did not contradict natural law and they didn't contradict Eternal Law, they contradicted human laws which contradicted natural and eternal laws - and maybe poorly interpreted Divine Laws (like allowing divorce by the hardness of their hearts - why was this a good law?).   "The deity of Christ and the abrogation of the Law of Moses were well beyond the pale of Judaism." doesn't make much sense to me, the whole point of Christianity is that Jesus  completes and fulfills all the messianic prophecies perfectly.
